# nftables: Set packet mark from raw payload

Tags: linux, iptables, linux-networking, nftables

I'm trying to set a packet's mark field to a 32-bit field in the (layer-5) header, using `nft add rule inet filter output udp dport 31337 meta mark set @th,96,32`. (I'm pulling second dword in the layer-5 header, but because the extraction starts at the offset of the layer-4 header I add 64 bits to get to the UDP payload.)

However, I get `Error: datatype mismatch: expected packet mark, expression has type integer`. The `integer` type in nftables is variable-length; the `mark` type is a specialization of the `integer` type that's exactly 32 bits long. I can't figure out how to cast or otherwise convince nftables that the type is actually OK.

Any insights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I'm using nftables 0.9.0, and [this bug](https://git.netfilter.org/nftables/commit/?id=6340734d7034d2424d3a5e34c3042c97a63b8b2d) wasn't fixed until 0.9.1.